# Facebook API - cover photo image not showing

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a simple bit of PHP to retrieve cover photos.

```
function get_fb_image($id) {
  global $facebook;
  $img = $facebook->api('/'.$id.'?fields=cover');
  return $img["cover"]["source"];
}
```

The string it returns is (for example) https://scontent-a.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ash3/t1.0-9/s720x720/10292482_276536685841029_1024651999315765938_n.jpg which is the correct image. When I try and put that in a simple  tag however it does not work, there is no image. I have tried swapping to http instead of https and I even tried with an access token to no avail, any ideas? Thanks!

You can see the rendered page here http://comedyinenglish.de/performers/caroline-clifford/ - the image is rendered near the 'xxx'

**UPDATE**
It's occured to me the image is just not showing in Chrome, any ideas? Security issue? Have tried http:// as well as https

Comment: **RESOLVED** OMG it was the plugin 'Disconnect' So sorry to waste everyones time - hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the PHP SDK of Facebook to try this out, but you can get the cover image using the graphs api like this:

**test.php**

```
<?php

function getCoverImage($user_or_page_id) {
    $jsonResult = json_decode(
        file_get_contents(
            'https://graph.facebook.com/'. $user_or_page_id .'?fields=cover'));
    return $jsonResult->cover->source;
}

?>

<img src="<?php echo getCoverImage('carolinecliffordcomedy') ?>" >
```

I've confirmed this working for me:

[image]

Comment: The img tag is rendered as
`<img src="http://scontent-a.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ash3/t1.0-9/s720x720/10292482_276536685841029_1024651999315765938_n.jpg">`

Comment: If you try to visit that URL `http://scontent-a.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ash3/t1.0-9/s720x720/10292482_276536‌​685841029_1024651999315765938_n.jpg` you will get error: `Invalid Request` - that's why the image isn't rendering.

Comment: Yeah the URLs don't stay valid for long, you need to use the API, the new image is http://scontent-a.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ash3/t1.0-9/s720x720/10292482_276536685841029_1024651999315765938_n.jpg for now

Comment: You can see the rendered page here http://comedyinenglish.de/performers/caroline-clifford/ - the image is rendered near the 'xxx'

Comment: Yes as per my comments the problem was due to a Chrome extension I had installed, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use curl function to get the results.I have used this code in my application and i got the result.Please try this code:

```
function curl_get_file_contents($URL) {
     $ch = curl_init();
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,0); 
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 400);
     $contents = curl_exec($ch);
     $err  = curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
     curl_close($ch);
     $contents=json_decode($contents,true);
     if ($contents)
         return $contents;
     else
         return FALSE;
}
    $page_user_name = 'carolinecliffordcomedy';  
    $url = "https://graph.facebook.com/$page_user_name?fields=cover";  
    $details =curl_get_file_contents($url);
    <img src="<?php echo $details['cover']['source']; ?>" height="250" width="250" />
```

Comment: Hi I tried this on my page and the image is still not showing in Chrome please see http://comedyinenglish.de/performers/caroline-clifford/ next to the xxx

Comment: When i clicked the link i can see the picture even i chrome. Can you please send me a screenshot.

Comment: As per my comments on the original question, the problem was due to a Chrome extension I have installed. Thanks for all your help, Caroline